# a presigned post in boto3 is the same as a browser based post with rest api signature calulucation server side?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

for the past 3 days I have been attempting to manually sign restapi post calls from the users browser. I have failed. I continue to get a `signature mismatch` error: So now I am going to try boto3. Boto3 it seems is used when you upload a file to your server then send it to amazon. I would rather do a browser based post.

I am reading the docs from boto3 on presigned posts and I am unsure. Is a browser based post the same as a presigned post in boto 3? 
http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3.html#generating-presigned-posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why yes. yes it is:

```
Returns
A dictionary with two elements: url and fields. Url is the url to post to. Fields is a dictionary filled with the form fields and respective values to use when submitting the post. For example:

{'url': 'https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com
'fields': {'acl': 'public-read',
'key': 'mykey', 'signature': 'mysignature', 'policy': 'mybase64 encoded policy'}

}
```